# python IOError [Errno 13] string vs Tk

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, tkinter, tk-toolkit

When I use Tk.askopenfiledialogbox and choose the directory I want, then open each file with `open(files, "r")` it works fine. However, when I hard code the path into a string I get access denied IOError [Errno13]. Here is my code:

```
   data_path = "C:\Data\DataSubDir"  
   datadir = [x[0] for x in os.walk(data_path)]
   for dataset in datadir[1:]:
        for files in glob.glob(dataset):
             with open(files,'r') as dest_f:
                  data_iter = c.reader(dest_f, 
                                       delimiter = ',', 
                                       quotechar = '"')
                   data = [data for data in data_iter]
                   csv = np.asarray(data, dtype = None)
```

I would like to solve this with out changing permissions. Also, if someone could also explain why choosing file through a Tk dialog box gets rid of the permission issue that would be awesome (and offer a solution too! ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either escape your backslashes

```
data_path = "C:\\Data\\DataSubDir"
```

or use a raw string:

```
data_path = r"C:\Data\DataSubDir"
```

With a Tk dialog box the string is in the correct format.

Comment: I figured it out. I was not specifying actual files in the open function. I needed to add "\\*.csv" to dataset. I think I am going to delete this question as it was my fault... Thanks though, really appreciated. Your answer made me find my mistake :)